# can't display the content of an iframe

Tags: iframe

I have a little problem. I use a "direct link" to connect to my member zone... like http://mydomain.com/?user=AAAA&pass=BBBB

When I use it on direct link, in a `<a href="...">` it works like a charm. The script redirect me and I have my content.

I would like ton include it in an iframe... but the content of the iFrame stays blank... no content.

http://mydomain.com/?user=AAAA&pass=BBBB does a redirection to another script...

Here is my code :

```
<iframe src="http://mail.expa13.fr/?user=<?php echo $user['mail']?>&pass=<?php echo $user['competences']?>"></iframe>
<a href="http://mail.expa13.fr/?user=<?php echo $user['mail']?>&pass=<?php echo $user['competences']?>" target="_blank">test</a>
```

If i click on the "a link", it works. New windows open...
But if I set on a iFrame... it's like there is no call...

You can try with user=test&pass=123456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, there is an option in the webmail i use (roundcube).

In the config file there is an option for x_frame_origine, default "sameorigine". We can deactivate the option with "false"... and it works ^^

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem is not in your code.
I think the server by somehow it detect the request is sent for not a normal browser or for an IFRAME tag. And then server reject the request.
Many service website do that. E.g. google.com

:-)

Comment: Oh ! Ok ! So... I have to try differently